# javascript parameter function not working in href

Tags: javascript

I have a function that create LI and href element.

```
function getsubject(s) {

    if (s <= 10) {
        var sub = ['Choose subject','math', 'physics', 'chemistry', 'biology'];
    } else {
        var sub = [ 'Choose subject','math', 'physics', 'chemistry', 'biology', 'accounts', 'BMT'];
    }

    var subList = sub.length;

    // var subl = document.getElementById("listul");
    // var a =  document.querySelectorAll('#listul .sli').length;

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sli");
    while(elements.length > 0){
         elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }

    var liElem="";
    for(var a =0;a<subList;a++){
        liElem += '<li class="sli"><a  href="#" onclick="ub('+sub[a]+');">'+sub[a]+'</a></li>';
    }

    document.getElementById('listul').innerHTML=liElem;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="list select_style">
    <ol id="listul">
      <li><a href="">choose subject</a></li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

when I passing using created function without parameter that work.
when I passing parameters from function can't work.

Comment: share it somewhere

Comment: your ub function parameters are not being passed as literals you should try onclick="ub(\"'+sub[a]+'\");">'+sub[a]+'</a></li>

Comment: It is helpful to open the developer tools of the browser (commonly the F12 key) - then the JavaScript debugger will show you where your problem lays...

Comment: Do not define the subList inside the function, this way it is undefined when you use it in the for loop. Define the subList outside of the function, then give it the value inside the function without the keyword var.

Answer (score 0):

## Quotes

You must pass variables with quotes into onclick.

For now `getsubject(s)` appends string:

```
<li class="sli"><a  href="#" onclick="ub(chemistry);">chemistry</a></li>
```

You can note that onclick handler is invalid as it invokes `ub` function on undefined value `chemistry`.

But you can call functions on strings like this `ub("chemistry")`.

So the solution is to place quotes around the values in the function call:

```
for(var a =0;a<subList;a++){
    liElem += '<li class="sli"><a  href="#" onclick="ub(\''+sub[a]+'\');">'+sub[a]+'</a></li>';
}
```

## Template literal

Better approach (but not available on all browsers is to use ECMAScript template literals:

```
for(var a =0;a<subList;a++){
    liElem += `
        <li class="sli">
            <a href="#" onclick="ub('${sub[a]}');">
                ${sub[a]}
            </a>
        </li>
    `;
}
```

Template literal can be used as normal string with `""` or `''` quotes, but it can be multiline and could contain notation `${variable}` which means to place value of `variable` in that place in the string.

## JQuery approach

It's worth to consider something better than plain text html rendering.

The equivalent code using jQuery looks like this:

```
var liNode = $('<li class="sli"></li>');
$('<a href="#"></a>').click(function() {
    // Call ud from the handler when link is clicked
    ud(value);
}).appendTo(liNode);
liNode.appendTo($('.sli'));
```